# parse xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

i want to parse xml file in java. my code is this. but when run it wrong data appear in console. my xml file such as this

```
    <set>
   <employe>
     <name>reza</name>
     <id>1</id>>
    </employe> 
   <employee>
      <name>ali</name>
      <id>2</id>
   </employee>
    </set>
```

and my code is this:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = builder.parse(file.toFile());
 Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
 if (!root.hasChildNodes()) {
    paths.add(file);
 } else {
   System.out.println("Element Name in: "+file.getFileName());
   System.out.println("Root element: "
                       + "Total count: " + root.getChildNodes().getLength());
   for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = root.getChildNodes().item(i);
        if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() != 0) {
            System.out.println("name: "+ node.getNodeName() + " size:"
                               + node.getChildNodes().getLength());
           }
         }
      }
```

and in console this data display

```
 Element Name in: file.xml
 Root element: Total count: 5
 name: employe size:5
 name: employee size:5
```

what is my problem?

Comment: You haven't said why the output you are getting is wrong, or what you expected to get out.  We can't help until we know what you intended to happen.

Comment: @Jim Garrison i want to count node element in this code. in fact employee   count is 2 but display 5. why?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure the nodes you are getting is of the type element, otherwise, whitespace may get counted the same way as an element.